# Why this comparision between 2 BigDecimal fail?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Into a Java application I have a unit test that contains the following situation:

```
BigDecimal rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected = new BigDecimal(2.85000);
BigDecimal rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioDB = null;

rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioDB = pucManager.getRendimentoLordoProvvisorio(date);

assertTrue(rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected.compareTo(rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioDB) == 0);
```

the value of the **rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected** variable is manually setted to **2.85000** and the obtained value **rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioDB** is **2.85000**.

The problem is that when I do this comparision into the **assertTrue()** JUnit function

```
assertTrue(rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected.compareTo(rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioDB) == 0);
```

it fail because the **rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected** seems to be **2.850000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625** and not **2.85000** (as setted).

Why? How can I modify the previous code to set the **rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected** to the expected value **2.85000**?

Comment: You initialize `rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected` using a double which is not precise. Try initializing it with a String instead.

Comment: I wonder why you didn't even read what the JavaDoc of [`BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-). It tells you that `double` is not precise what you should use instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are initializing the BigDecimal with a floating point value, by calling the constructor with a double. Doubles are floating point numbers. Use a String:

```
BigDecimal rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected = new BigDecimal("2.85000");
```

You should read the [documentation of BigDecimal regarding calling the `double` version of the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-).

When you use a BigDecimal, you are converting a base two floating point to a base 10 floating point number. There is no perfect base two floating point representation of the number 2.85, the best approximation seems to be a number close to:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(2.85)
Decimal('2.850000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625')
```

You should read more about floating point, for example [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 6):

Use `BigDecimal rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected = new BigDecimal("2.85000");` instead of `BigDecimal rendimentoLordoProvvisiorioExpected = new BigDecimal(2.85000);`
What you did was build a BigDecimal from a double, and doubles are not precise.

Comment: What do you mean that double are note precise? It is an approximation or what?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Research .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Because you are calling the BigDecimal constructor with a double. Doubles are floating point numbers. That's why you should use a string.

Comment: Exactly. Tom's link explains it in detail.

Comment: Well... if it were so obvious that he is calling BigDecimal ctor with a double he wouldn't have made this question in the first place. It is clear that OP is missing this link, and is missing the issues with floating point.

Comment: No one said it was obvious.